# Examine the Maximum and Minimum Value

Tags: calculus

I have to do the following problem, and I need help.

> Examine the function $f(x,y) = \dfrac{-3x}{x^2+y^2+1}$ with respect to maximum and minimum.

Comment: also, in the future, please do not use the imperative (Examine, Do, Prove, etc...) with the members of this site. It can be thought of as rude.

Answer (score 3):

**Maybe** you are expected to find the place(s) where the partials are $0$, find out at which of these two places the function is bigger, and where it is less, write down that you have a maximum at the first, a minimum at the second, and go on to the next question.

But in principle, this is **not enough**.  And it is not hard to come up with examples where a mechanical approach of this type leads to the wrong conclusion.

Let's think about $f(x,y)$.  It is not hard to see that if you take a big circle around the origin, then outside that circle $f(x,y)$ is close to $0$.  The equation $z=f(x,y)$ determines a smooth surface.

Examination of the critical points shows that inside the circle, $f(x,y)$ takes on the values $3/2$ and $-3/2$.  Thus there are a global max and a global min, and these must occur inside the circle.  So the global max/min must be local max/min, the top of a hill or the bottom of a valley.

It follows that at the global max and min, the surface must have flattened out, that is, the partials must be $0$.  But by setting the partials equal to $0$, we found the *only two* places where such a flattening out occurred, and we are finished.

In this particular case, you could also notice that $f(-x,y)=-f(x,y)$, and that the function is positive when $x<0$ and negative when $x>0$.  So when you have located the maximum, the minimum value is automatically the negative of the maximum value.  Symmetry is your friend!

There is a "test" you may be taught, involving the second partials, that (usually) enables you to determine whether a critical point gives a local max or a local min.  While this test is of great theoretical importance, it is often difficult to use.  The second partials for your $f(x,y)$ are not much fun to calculate, so in this case the test that uses second partials would be unpleasant to carry out.

Answer (score 0):

look for points where the partials vanish simultaneously (called critical points by some), in this case
$$f_x=[-3(x^2+y^2+1)+6x^2]/(x^2+y^2+1)^2, f_y=6xy/(x^2+y^2+1)^2$$
which are both zero only at $(x,y)=(1,0), (-1,0)$.  now the simplest thing to do is evaluate the function at those points (if a function such as $f$ has a local max/min at some point where it is differentiable, then it is a critical point; note that $f$ is differentiable everywhere).  we have $f(1,0)=-3/2, f(-1,0)=3/2$ so those are the min and max respectively.

---

added for nitpickers

given the behavior at infinity
$$
\lim_{|(x,y)|\to\infty}f(x,y)=0
$$
$f$ clearly has a global max/min (continuous on a large closed disk where the boundary values are small wrt the claimed max/min)

Comment: @Aline, if you like yoyo's answer, you could vote it up by clicking the up-arrow. If you like it a lot, you could accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: the crucial phrase is "$\it if$ a function has a local max/min...." You have found the critical points, but you haven't established that either one is a maximum or a minimum, not even locally.